# Does Mathematica store hidden information for matrix objects?

Tags: matrix, bugs, expression-test

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

I found a case where calling one built-in function (`HermitianMatrixQ`) for a given matrix changes the behavior of another built-in function (`AntihermitianMatrixQ`) for the *same* matrix object. Here is the code:

```
M = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}

AntihermitianMatrixQ[M]    (* output: True *)
HermitianMatrixQ[M]        (* output: False *)
AntihermitianMatrixQ[M]    (* output: False -- WRONG! *)
```

I observed this in Mathematica 10.0.0.0 on Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

The behavior is "stateful" in the sense that re-evaluating the assignment to `M` restores the correct behavior of `AntihermitianMatrixQ` until the next time the function `HermitianMatrixQ` is called for the same object, from which point on `AntihermitianMatrixQ` gives the incorrect result again.

I did some experimentation and found the following:

- The "state" is per object: When you define several array variables, the functions behave independently for each of the array objects, in the way described above.
- The problem does not occur for all matrices, but it is not limited to the given 2x2 case, either. (In fact I found it when debugging a calculation with 4x4 Dirac gamma matrices.)
- The function `SymmetricMatrixQ` intereferes with the behavior of `AntihermitianMatrixQ` in the same way.
- The result of `AntisymmetricMatrixQ` is affected in the same way.
- Printing the `FullForm` of the object does not give any indication of a change to the object itself.

**My question is therefore:**

- Does Mathematica store any per-object data for matrices that is not displayed in `FullForm` but that can affect the behavior of functions as described above?
- If so, is there any way to display or to clear this kind of additional data?

Note: I created a support request with Wolfram Research regarding this strange behavior. So far I got no response, however. I would also appreciate independent confirmation of this behavior, to exclude the possibility that something is wrong with my particular installation of Mathematica.

**UPDATE**: I got a response to my support request (CASE:3202743) from WRI. They confirm that `AntisymmetricMatrixQ` is not behaving properly and that an incident report has been created. Many thanks also to @ilian for pursuing this matter. I would still be interested in answers to my questions as formulated -- both out of curiosity and in order to improve debugging options.

Comment: I see the same behavior on OS X MMA ver.10.0.1.0

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thank you, I've submitted a bug report to the appropriate developers.

Comment: I see the same behavior in MMA ver. 10.1.0 on Win7-64bit. This is weird!

Comment: Confirmed on Linux in *Mathematica* versions 10.0.2 and 10.1.0.

Comment: @MarcoB, jkuczm: Thanks for confirming!

Comment: I think a workaround might be to use an explicit `SameTest`. `{AntihermitianMatrixQ[m, SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)], 
 HermitianMatrixQ[m, SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)], 
 AntihermitianMatrixQ[m, SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)]}`

Comment: @chuy: Yes, this gives correct behavior for me, too, thanks. It also adds further curiosities: The `HermitianMatrixQ` with custom `SameTest` still destroys the behavior of `AntihermitianMatrixQ` without `SameTest`. `AntihermitianMatrixQ` with custom `SameTest` is unaffected, however, and it even restores the behavior of the default  `AntihermitianMatrixQ` call! Overall the picture gets very complicated. I suspect an internal optimization gone wrong behind this.

Comment: Indeed there is something certainly amiss. See this: `f = (Print[Equal[##]]; Equal[##]) &; AntihermitianMatrixQ[m, SameTest -> f]` as opposed to `HermitianMatrixQ[m, SameTest -> f]`.

Comment: for g = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};k = m = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}; AntihermitianMatrixQ[g] returns True and AntihermitianMatrixQ[k] returns False

Comment: A simple workaround is to create a new expression, e.g. `AntihermitianMatrixQ[2 M / 2]` or `AntihermitianMatrixQ[0.0 + M]`

Comment: I think the answers are yes and no, respectively.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I take your comment to be a direct answer to the OP's two questions, in which case I wonder if you could elaborate on it. What information is stored about matrices, or maybe more in general about objects in MMA, that is not accessible through `FullForm` or similar constructs?

Comment: @MarcoB I really do not have a good answer to this. I only know about the structured matrix information storage because I looked into the bug that started this thread. I think information is stored for all "raw" objects e.g. `Graph`, `Association`, and several others.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for getting back to me anyway. I guess the prevailing advice is that we shouldn't dwell on the inner workings of MMA too much anyway, but sometimes I can't help  but wonder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now fixed in version 10.2.

```
In[1]:= m = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};

In[2]:= {AntihermitianMatrixQ[m], HermitianMatrixQ[m], AntihermitianMatrixQ[m]} 

Out[2]= {True, False, True}
```

As per the comments, yes, there is information stored in the internal representation of matrices (for example, a symmetry flag) and no, it is not accessible from top level code.